# Edit a JSON file in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to update a file in asset folder `assets/firstboot.json`. I am trying to use `http.patch` to update it. But it is not actually updating the file. Is there a way to update the JSON file content on disk in typescript? Thanks in advance!

The code I am trying is:

assets/firstboot.json

```
{
    "firstbootCompleted": false
}
```

In service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public setConfigStatus(config) {
    console.log(config);
    return this.http.patch('assets/firstboot.json', config);
  }

}
```

In component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { SettingService } from '../setting/setting.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-config',
  templateUrl: './config.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./config.component.css']
})
export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {

  public errorFlag = false;
  public alertMessage: string;
  public username: string = "admin";
  public domain: string = "domain";
  public password: string = "password";
  public userFormData: any = {"username":this.username+'@'+this.domain,"password":this.password};

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private settingService: SettingService, private configService: ConfigService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.login({"username":this.username,"authSource":this.domain,"password":this.password}).subscribe();
  }

  public updatePassword(userFormValue) {
      this.settingService.updateLocalUser(userFormValue).subscribe(
        res => {
              this.setConfigStatus();
              this.authService.logout();
              this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
            }, err => {
            this.alertMessage = 'Password was not updated.';
            this.errorFlag = true;
        } );
    }

    public setConfigStatus(){
      return this.configService.setConfigStatus({"firstbootCompleted": true});
    }

}
```

Comment: No! it is not possible

Comment: I am ok if there is any other way instead of http.patch. In jasmine test framework, they are writing file on disk. So I think there must be a way to write/edit file to disk in typescript.

Comment: In my knowledge, you will not be able to use anything to modify client-side files.

Comment: U could try to use $http.post and $http.delete but not sure if it would work.

Comment: Writing/editing a file is done by a server side language, Typescript anyway can't do anything regarding this.

Comment: Assets is just static files that can be served alongside the website files. To actually update them you'd have to make a call to the server and update the file through the server side code. Doesn't really matter much, although yes there are differances, what kind of http request you make

Comment: You can use LocalStore, but not a json file